# Series Sum up to N terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have been trying to find the sum of a series given by
$ t(n) = \frac{1}{2^n-1}$, up to N terms. All I could do is to see that the difference of the successive denominators form a GP.

Kindly help me with a solution or at least a hint.

Comment: Do you have any motive to suspect that this has a simple or closed form solution?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2^n-1}\simeq\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{2^n}+0.6=1.6-\frac1{2^N}$

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281/%282%5En-1%29%29%20from%201%20to%20N) gives

$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n-1} = \frac{\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(N+1)-\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(1)}{\log(2)}$

where $\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}$ is the [1/2-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) but I don't feel any wiser.